# Removing old code from header

Tags: headers

In our site, we've got some old code sitting in the header. I'm guessing it originated from a plugin we used to use (embedding Scribd content into the site), but we are no longer using it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.scribd.com/javascripts/view.js"></script>
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to get rid of this script. It's not in header.php - so where would I go to edit this out?

Comment: This is most likely injected through the `wp_head` hook into your `<head>` tag. Did you check the list of activated plugins or did you try to peak into the `functions.php` file in your current theme directory?

Comment: I don't see any reference to the scribd javascript in functions.php.

Looking through activated (and inactive) plugins, don't see anything related to scribd anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SSH, go to your `wp-content` directory and grep it.

```
/ grep -HRn 'scribd' .
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the code. There was a plugin that had not deleted itself completely. All gone - thanks for the grep idea!